# Link unresolved error with VS2008 Boost ASIO and OpenSSL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, openssl, boost-asio

I have downloaded Boost version 1.51 from [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download/).  The installer seems to be a little flaky, but I think I managed to download most of the 1.51 files.  For the files that were missing, I found another [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.51.0/) and managed to download the rest of those as well.  I also downloaded OpenSSL version j 64 bit version.  I am trying to build the code from this [example client code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp).  The linker generates 51 unresolved external errors.  Here are the first 20, which appear to be at least somewhat similar to the errors others have complained about:

```
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_reason_error_string referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int)const " (?message@ssl_category@detail@error@asio@boost@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_get_error referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_server_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_client_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TLSv1_server_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TLSv1_client_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TLSv1_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv3_server_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv3_client_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv3_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv2_server_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv2_client_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_new referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv2_method referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::context(enum boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)" (??0context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@W4method@context_base@123@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::~context(void)" (??1context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_ex_data referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::~context(void)" (??1context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_get_ex_data referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::~context(void)" (??1context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_verify referenced in function "public: class boost::system::error_code __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::set_verify_mode(int,class boost::system::error_code &)" (?set_verify_mode@context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE?AVerror_code@system@4@HAAV564@@Z)
1>TestBoostASIO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_get_verify_callback referenced in function "public: class boost::system::error_code __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::set_verify_mode(int,class boost::system::error_code &)" (?set_verify_mode@context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE?AVerror_code@system@4@HAAV564@@Z)
```

I have read other questions here about the problem of linking Boost with OpenSSL and have tried the suggested steps to solve the problem.  This includes:

1. Added the path C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include to the Additional Include Directories.
2. Added C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\static to the Additional Library Directories.  Have also tried specifying the C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\ path as well, with the same result.
3. Added libeay32MDd.lib and ssleay32MDd.lib to Additional Dependencies for the linker additional dependencies.

I still get these link errors even after doing the above.  I have also tried building my project with __stdcall instead of the default __cdecl - which gave compile errors on the call to signal which is expecting __cdecl; so I don't think that is it.  I have tried everything I could think of.  Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I can try that would fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to build the solution by building with the 32-bit versions of both the Boost ASIO and OpenSSL libraries.  I now suspect that this is a bug in the Windows 64 bit version of Boost::ASIO and have submitted a [bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7893).

To get rid of the unresolved link errors, the 32 bit version of the VS2008 [redistributables](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) also need to be downloaded, along with the 32 bit version of OpenSSL and built against the 32 bit version of Boost.